# Most efficient way to build list of highest prices from queryset?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

In one page of my app, I'm trying to display the most expensive car for each company. My models look roughly like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    headcount = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company_unique = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

So, I want to build a list consisting of every company's single most expensive Car object.

I approached the problem like this:

```
company_list = Company.objects.all()
most_expensive = []
for company in company_list:
    most_expensive.append(Car.objects.filter(company_unique=company.id).order_by("-price")[0])
```

However, this seems to be a very inefficient method. I can see with Django Debug Toolbar that this code is making way too many mysql queries.

Can someone suggest a better way to build this list that would hit MySQL maybe just once or twice?

Comment: Using these builtins may reduce your query count: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/#retrieve-everything-at-once-if-you-know-you-will-need-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you're dealing with is quite a common case, an obvious solution is seemingly lacking.

**Solution 1**, found in [this article](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/). You could probably try something along these lines:

```
companies = Company.objects.annotate(max_price=Max('car__price'))
values = tuple((company.id, company.max_price) for company in companies)

expensive_cars = Car.objects.extra(where=['(company_unique_id, price) IN %s' % (values,)])
```

Can't say I like the solution - `.extra` should be avoided - but I can't think of a better way. I am also not entirely sure this will work at all.

**Solution 2**, sub-optimal. You can make use of [custom `Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch).

```
prefetch = Prefetch('cars', queryset=Car.objects.order_by('-price'), to_attr='cars_by_price')
companies = Company.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch)

most_expensive_cars = []
for company in companies:
    most_expensive_cars.append(list(company.cars_by_price.all())[0])
```

That should definitely work and fetch everything in two queries, but is extremely wasteful , since it will load all `Cars` related to given set of `Companies` into memory. Do note that `list()` part is not optional: wherever you take a slice or index, a queryset is copied and produces a separate DB query, therefore negating the prefetch, while instantiating a list will use the result of said prefetch.

If you need to access companies afterwards, like `Car.company`, don't shy away from using `select_related`, as suggested by Erik in the comments.

Comment: I think Solution 1 is the way I'm going to go. In my case, I found I had to cast the two values to strings, eg: `values = tuple(( str(company.id), str(company.max_price)) for company in companies)` ... otherwise I would get MySQL errors.

Answer (score 0):

I swore this was how I was able to handle it, but it seems like I must be mistaken.

<s>I think that's possible with [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/):</s>

```
most_expensive = Car.objects.values('company_unique').annotate(Max('price'))
```

The following is in raw SQL, which has its benefits, but I feel like there may be a cleaner way:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Max(price), company_unique FROM Car GROUP BY company_unique");
price_company = cursor.fetchall()

# This still does one query per car, only it fetches one item at a time.
most_expensive = [Cars.objects.get(price=pc[0],company_unique=pc[1]) 
                    for pc in price_company]
```

If you really wanted to limit it to *one* query, then you might be able to leverage `raw`:

```
most_expensive = Cars.objects.raw("""
   SELECT * FROM Cars 
     INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT Max(price) as price, company_unique FROM Car GROUP BY company_unique) m 
       ON m.price = Cars.price, m.company_unique = Cars.company_unique
""")
```

The problem with using `raw` is that it is not database agnostic, so any refactoring will need to involve re-writing this query. (Oracle, for example, has a different secondary query syntax).

I feel like I should point out that the `SELECT Max(price) as price, company_unique FROM Car GROUP BY company_unique` query will be executed no matter what — if you're using a more Django-native solution it will happen behind the scenes.

Comment: That queryset doesn't seem to consist of Car objects anymore. At least, it no longer has all the fields of a Car object like 'name'. When I pass that into my template, a table is built with the right number of rows, but each cell is empty.

Comment: that's a different issue. You probably have an error in your template (which is not included in the question so it's not relevent here) This really answers the question

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question in any way. If you read the example OP gave, it is clear that he expects to get `Car` instances, not just maximum prices.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to company called something like "priciest_car" and override save such that every time you save a company, you loop through it's related cars and sets the most expensive one to priciest_car. then when you need to call the most expensive cars for each company, you can just loop through each company and add `company.priciest_car` to the list. It's one loop, one sql call each itteration. the only extra work would be when you save a company but it will be per company so it shouldn't take too long. If it does, find a way to only make it set the "priciest_car" field only when you know it's been changed.